# add items to cart Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say customer is adding multiple products to cart.
Add car, apartment, tour, some coupons. 
Products belong to categories.
Category has name attribute. 
But how to give different attributes to car, apartment, tour, coupon?
I can't definitely create everything from product model.
So should I create different models for each category and connect through has many ro products model?
Or am I going to wrong direction?
Thanks

Comment: Is the category purely a label, or do items in the categories actually behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a **Category** for individual product seems to be a good approach here. Since your `Category` differs according to attributes. What you can do is create One more model, let's say: `MasterCategory` which has many `Category` and `Category` belongs to `MasterCategory`, which means for your **`MasterCategory`** `Cars` you'll have `Audi, BMW, Nissan etc etc. categories` and then link your products to their respective vendors in a table `products_categories` which will have `product_id, category_id`.

In my opinion, schema could go like this:

```
ProductsCategory:
product_id, category_id

MasterCategory:
id, name, created_at, updated_at

Category:
id, master_category_id, parent_id, name, position, name, permalink
```

For e.g. - A `car` MasterCategory will look like this:

```
#<MasterCategory id: 1, name: "cars", created_at: "2012-02-14 13:03:45", updated_at: "2012-02-14 13:03:45">
```

and its `categories` will be:

```
[#<Category id: 1, master_category_id: 1, parent_id: nil, position: 0, name: "cars", created_at: "2012-02-14 13:03:45", updated_at: "2012-02-14 13:03:45", permalink: "cars">, #<Category id: 2, master_category_id: 1, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: "Audi", created_at: "2012-02-14 13:03:45", updated_at: "2012-02-14 13:32:51", permalink: "cars/audi">]
```

Now you can have two methods `parent` and `children` in your `Category` Model using `parent_id` attribute to locate and traverse **master** and **sub categories** easily. And you can use `permalink` attribute to easily locate a category which is under another category with one query: `Category.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])` and can display all the products related with this particular category. In future when you'll scale, I can bet you, you'll require this `position` attribute to manage position of your categories to display on your page. And in last `master_category_id` will give you an ease in life with:

```
car = MasterCategory.find(1)
car.categories.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
```

All the best!! :)